# http.post não está funcionando

Tags: angular, ionic2, typescript

Estou tentando enviar um formulário para uma API com o **http.post** do Angular, mas não estou conseguindo:

**Código:**

```
save(auditoria):Observable <{}>{
    let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.post(`${Utils.WEBSERVICE}/api/audit`, auditoria, options).map( (res:Response) => res.json());
}
```

**Assim é como fica no console**

> Request URL:http://147.1.5.114/webservice/api/audit
>
> Request Method:OPTIONS
>
> Status Code:404 Not Found

Na minha API não existe nada que receba o verb Options, quando eu faço o mesmo envio usando o **POSTMAN** ocorre tudo normal, só não funciona pelo aplicativo que estou construindo.

Comment: Você habilitou o CORS no seu Backend?

Comment: @HiagoSouza, está habilitado sim

Comment: Inclusive, se eu faço a mesma requisição usando o Postman, funciona de boa

Comment: Veja se o endpoint realmente é esse e verifique o formato dos dados que você está passando, verifique se o payload do json bate com os dados esperados no server.